# Simple form for params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have 2 models, blogs and posts

```
  resources :blogs do
    resources :posts
  end
```

So, also  i have an association. One blog can have a lot of posts. So I put the link to new post in the index of blog:

```
= link_to 'New Post', new_blog_post_path(@blog)
```

And then it redirects you to new post, which renders a form like this:

```
  = simple_form_for(@post) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :content

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit
```

And I'm getting an error:

> undefined method `posts_path'

I think simple form requires the blog_id but I could't find it. I tried to put @blog.id to simple form, but anyway i got an error (id for nil class)
How can I solve my problem?

Comment: There's no such thing as `posts_path`. Type `rake routes` and you'll see that the route you're looking for is probably `blog_posts_path`. That route will direct you to the index page for posts.

Comment: yes the question is how can i send correct rout from my form ?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used simple_form_for, but it looks to me like your resource has association that is assigned. So you'll need to include it in the form definition:

```
= simple_form_for([@blog, @post]) do |f|
= f.error_notification

.form-inputs
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :content

.form-actions
  = f.button :submit
```

And obviously you'll need to have @blog available in your controller action.

Link to the `form_for` docs:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

EDIT:

Not sure where `posts_path` is coming from in your code, but obviously that route doesn't exist as all `post` paths are dependent on `blog`s.

Is there anywhere where you reference a `post_path` in your code?

Comment: See the edit. The form will generate a `posts_path` as the url for the form, you tried putting in the [@blog, @post] in the `simple_form_for`? That should generate the correct route, something like `blog/:blog_id/posts`

Comment: yes, you are right, but i don't know how to correctly write a form

Comment: The use of `[@blog, @post]` in the `form_for` should do it, but you can also specify the other attributes of the form directly. See the link I posted and scroll down, you'll see a section with a form_for like this: `<%= form_for @post, as: :post, url: post_path(@post), method: :patch, html: { class: "edit_post", id: "edit_post_45" } do |f| %>` As you can see, you can specify all the usual things for a `<form>` element. So, you could try making it: `= simple_form_for([@blog, @post], url: blog_posts_path(@blog)) do |f|` :-)